# reach mail connection fails with 535

Tags: logback, smtp-auth

Below is an excerpt from my logback config for reachmail. 
I'm getting "Error occurred while sending e-mail notification. javax.mail.AuthenticationFai
ledException: 535 error: authentication failed, InvalidUsernameOrPassword http://easy-smtp.com/err
        at javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 error: authentication failed, InvalidUsernameOrPassword http://easy-smtp.com/err"

Here is my appender:

```
  <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
  <level>ERROR</level>
</filter>
<smtpHost>ssrs.reachmail.net</smtpHost>
<smtpPort>587</smtpPort>
<STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
<username>domain\\myuser</username>
<password>mypassword</password>
<to>user@example.com</to>
<from>user@example.com</from>
<subject>Exception: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
  <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{1}.%M - %m%n</pattern>
</layout>
</appender>
```

Is there anything missing in this config? It should connect like this???
My username and password are correct!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a single `\` in your username. The double `\` is not always required as the first `\` is most often used to escape the `\a` (in `Accountkey**\a**dmin`)

While less common, some characters in your password may also need to be escaped in the same fashion. This depends on your application's environment and tends to be most common in *NIX devices.

If all else fails, consider email our support line at support@reachmail.com for more specific handling of your issue.